# How to remove duplicate values in two arrays?

Tags: php

I dispose of two arrays with the following contents:

```
$arr1 = "one", "two", "three";
$arr2 = "one", "two";
```

I want to make sure to return an array containing only the value **"three"**;
In my applications in fact the values of `$arr1` represent the link to be included in a table, those of `$arr2` links already entered.
I tried using the function intersect but this returns the values that are duplicates, but I want to discard the duplicates and take only the values that are not present in `$arr2`;

```
$c = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$filter= array_diff($arr1 , $arr2 );
```